# Match current date with selection and return cell address

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I have a row containing dates:

```
05/10/15    06/10/15    07/10/15    08/10/15    09/10/15    10/10/15    11/10/15
D3:J3
```

I have a cell (`D5`) with the following value:

```
=NOW()
//Returns "07/10/15"
//The cell is formatted to exclude time.
```

I have this function (E5):

```
=ADDRESS(3,MATCH(D5,D3:J3,0),1,4)
```

The aim is to match the current date with a date from a given selection and return the cell address. The function does not work and I am not sure what I am missing.

I added the following function to check the values:

```
=IF(F3=D5,TRUE,FALSE)
```

This returns `FALSE`, which could be one of the reasons the main function is falling over.

```
NOW() != "07/10/15"
```

How can I fix this?

`TODAY() == "07/10/15"` which solved that half of the issue

The Function is now finding a match but return the value `C3` the value with the matched date is `F3` which is the value I want returning.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ADDRESS(3,MATCH(D5,D3:J3,0),1,4)
```

First is the Row number, Since your data is on Row 3 I entered 3, yet any other formula which return this value is good as well ( such as Row)

2nd you entered too many values to the `match` , `MATCH(D5,D3:J3,0)` will do.

3rd but not conclusive my now() is for time stamp while today() is for date only .

Comment: Hi I have formatted both all of the cells to display the date in the same format style but the function is falling over when it tries to perform the match

Comment: No it doesnt work, see my edit. when I try =IF(F3=D5,TRUE,FALSE) it returns false, so the values must be different somehow

Answer (score 1):

When using MATCH(), it's going to give you a column position relative to the beginning of your search array. I just extended your search array to start at the first column, so the relative column returned will be accurate to use with the ADDRESS() function. So, like this:

<strike>=ADDRESS(3, MATCH(D5,A3:J3),1)</strike>

Update: Ok, so previously left out needed parameters. We need a third parameter on MATCH() to tell it that we want it to match exactly. Also, if we throw in "4" as an additional parameter on ADDRESS(), then it will make it prettier. So, like this:

```
=ADDRESS(3, MATCH(D5,A3:J3,0),4)
```

Comment: Hi, I think the problem is with trying to match NOW() to the date in the columns. Please see my edit.

Comment: I see your edit. I'm using NOW(), formatted to shortdate, and it works.

Comment: Could you explain how to format to shortdate? I have formatted the cells to display the date as shown but I assume this is something else.

Comment: Sweet, looks like you got it!

Comment: Yea I used TODAY() instead of NOW()

Comment: Ah, yeah, using TODAY() (date) makes more sense than NOW() (datetime). Good job

Comment: Actually not quite there, the function works but returns C3 when the cell with the matched value is F3. Is this what you got?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91632/discussion-between-w3ave-and-brian-peach).